# Error 16112 - How to connect to Ebay without interactivity?

Tags: python, ebay-sdk

So, I'm trying to use the ebaysdk-python module, to connect to ebay and get a list of orders. After struggle a little bit with the connection, I've finally have found the ebay.yaml syntax. I have then configured the user and password, but I'm receiving this Error 16112.

So, this is my question: is there a way to connect to ebay without interactivity? I mean, without the need to give the permission to get the token and such (oauth)?

Comment: 16112 = The authentication method you are using is invalid. Please use the eBay Authentication & Authorization method.

Comment: Yes, I know that. What I need is a way to log in into ebay without needing to open the popup with authentication and authorization...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found the way to do this: I have created a user token using the method auth'n'auth. This user token have almost a year of validity, so it can be used for my purpose. Now, there is another question around that.